# Read continuously from a named pipe

Tags: go, named-pipes

I would like to know what other options I have in order to read continuously from a named pipe using golang. My current code relies on a infinite for loop running inside a gorutine; but hat keeps one CPU at 100% usage.

```
func main() {
....

var wg sync.WaitGroup
fpipe, _ := os.OpenFile(namedPipe, os.O_RDONLY, 0600)
defer fpipe.Close()

f, _ := os.Create("dump.txt")
defer f.Close()
var buff bytes.Buffer

wg.Add(1)
go func() {
        for {
          io.Copy(&buff, fpipe)
          if buff.Len() > 0 {
              buff.WriteTo(f)
           }
         }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: `io.Copy` "reads continuously", don't put it in a loop.

Comment: @JimB I guess I should mention that the writing side is not writing to the named pipe continuously. If I rely solely on io.Copy, the goroutine will terminate once EOF is reached.

Comment: See my solution below. Just add *another* open() on the pipe to open it os.O_WRONLY. Dont close it. Your loop will then work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A named pipe reader will receive EOF when there are no writers left. The solution outside of this code is to make sure there is always one writer process holding the file descriptor, though it doesn't need to write anything.

Within the Go program, if you want to wait for a new writer, you will have to poll the `io.Reader` in your for loop. Your current code does this with a busy loop, which will consume 100% of 1 cpu core. Adding a sleep and a way to return on other errors will work around the issue:

```
for {
    err := io.Copy(&buff, fpipe)
    if buff.Len() > 0 {
        buff.WriteTo(f)
    }

    if err != nil {
        // something other than EOF happened
        return
    }

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why runtime.Gosched doesn't do the job?

Comment: @Benjamin.E: You don't need `runtime.GoSched` because you're already yielding to other goroutines. Function/method calls and channel operations will yield, so `io.Copy` is completely sufficient. The problem is just that you're spinning as fast as possible when there's nothing there. Readers aren't going to be coming and going in sub-millisecond timeframes, so there's no reason to retry that quickly.

Comment: @JimB Please see my critique of your solution in my answer.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: while your's is somewhat more optimal, that condition os _only_ going to happen the moment a new writer connects since the `io.Copy` will block until that writer is gone. The maximum 100ms window of loss doesn't mean much for reliability since you can't guarantee your application is responsive in that time period anyway. Much simpler and more reliable is the first solution I mentioned, of simply just opening the named pipe for writing -- no need to poll, or watch the file descriptor at all.

Answer (score 3):

## Intro

As already written, a named pipe reader will receive an EOF if no writers are left.

However I find @JimB's solution less than optimal:

1. A named pipe has a maximum capacity (65kB, iirc), which may well get filled within the 100msec sleep period. When the buffer is filled, all writers would block for no good reason.
2. If a reboot happens, you will loose 50ms worth of data on average. Again, for no good reason.
3. If you want to use a static buffer for copying, [**`io.CopyBuffer(dst Writer, src Reader, buf []byte) (written int64, err error)`**](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyBuffer) would be the better solution, imho. But this is not even necessary, as [**`io.Copy`**](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=12490:12550#L349) (or the underlying implementation) actually allocates a buffer of 32kB.

## My approach

A better solution would be to wait for a write to happen and the immediately copy the contents of the named pipe to the destination file. On most systems, there is some sort of notification on file system events. The package [github.com/rjeczalik/notify](https://github.com/rjeczalik/notify) can be used to access the events we are interested in, as write events work cross platform on most of the important OSes. The other event which would be interesting for us is the removal of the named pipe, since we would not have anything to read from.

Hence, my solution would be:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/rjeczalik/notify"
)

const (
    MAX_CONCURRENT_WRITERS = 5
)

var (
    pipePath string
    filePath string
)

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&pipePath, "pipe", "", "/path/to/named_pipe to read from")
    flag.StringVar(&filePath, "file", "out.txt", "/path/to/output file")
    log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    var p, f *os.File
    var err error
    var e notify.EventInfo

    // The usual stuff: checking wether the named pipe exists etc
    if p, err = os.Open(pipePath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        log.Fatalf("Named pipe '%s' does not exist", pipePath)
    } else if os.IsPermission(err) {
        log.Fatalf("Insufficient permissions to read named pipe '%s': %s", pipePath, err)
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error while opening named pipe '%s': %s", pipePath, err)
    }
    // Yep, there and readable. Close the file handle on exit
    defer p.Close()

    // Do the same for the output file
    if f, err = os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        log.Fatalf("File '%s' does not exist", filePath)
    } else if os.IsPermission(err) {
        log.Fatalf("Insufficient permissions to open/create file '%s' for appending: %s", filePath, err)
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error while opening file '%s' for writing: %err", filePath, err)
    }
    // Again, close the filehandle on exit
    defer f.Close()

    // Here is where it happens. We create a buffered channel for events which might happen
    // on the file. The reason why we make it buffered to the number of expected concurrent writers
    // is that if all writers would (theoretically) write at once or at least pretty close
    // to each other, it might happen that we loose event. This is due to the underlying implementations
    // not because of go.
    c := make(chan notify.EventInfo, MAX_CONCURRENT_WRITERS)

    // Here we tell notify to watch out named pipe for events, Write and Remove events
    // specifically. We watch for remove events, too, as this removes the file handle we
    // read from, making reads impossible
    notify.Watch(pipePath, c, notify.Write|notify.Remove)

    // We start an infinite loop...
    for {
        // ...waiting for an event to be passed.
        e = <-c

        switch e.Event() {

        case notify.Write:
            // If it a a write event, we copy the content of the named pipe to
            // our output file and wait for the next event to happen.
            // Note that this is idempotent: Even if we have huge writes by multiple
            // writers on the named pipe, the first call to Copy will copy the contents.
            // The time to copy that data may well be longer than it takes to generate the events.
            // However, subsequent calls may copy nothing, but that does not do any harm.
            io.Copy(f, p)

        case notify.Remove:
            // Some user or process has removed the named pipe,
            // so we have nothing left to read from.
            // We should inform the user and quit.
            log.Fatalf("Named pipe '%s' was removed. Quitting", pipePath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to reiterate from above, the pipe's buffer is just that, a buffer, and it will accept data no matter the state of the reading process. There is no guarantee that the buffer will have been read at all in the event of failure, and telling yourself otherwise is just tempting fate. You have to accept that there is always the possibility of data loss when there's no acknowledgement. This does make a more responsive implementation however (at the cost of added complexity).

Comment: @JimB Off, you can loose data, however, it is less likely, and this solution is less prone to blocking the writers.

Comment: I was thinking as well to rely on a notification mechanism in order to avoid cluttered data.

Comment: Why does "  if p, err = os.Open(pipePath); os.IsNotExist(err)" block until the first write to the named pipe?

Comment: @AndyCini Digging down a bit, non-surprisingly I ended [finding a syscall](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4a778cdf3375d418062b3c3e9f6891cc9162e3d0/src/os/file_unix.go#L190). I assume that this blocks until the pipe is actually active. However, I do not see a problem with the block -  we only want to continue in case at least one entry was written to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: when the 'last writer' closes the pipe, you get an EOF even though there may be new writers that appear later.

Solution: open the pipe yourself for write and dont close it. Now you can treat the read side as a never ending read without ever getting EOF. Put the following directly after where you open your pipe for read:

```
nullWriter, err := os.OpenFile(pipePath, os.O_WRONLY, os.ModeNamedPipe)
if err != nil {
  logger.Crit("Error opening pipe for (placeholder) write", "err", err)
}
defer nullWriter.Close()
```